# JS Combine 2 separate array with keys

Tags: javascript

I have this code below consisting of 2 arrays with key pair values. What i'm currently trying to achieve is to combine this arrays into something like this.

`[{"id" : "1" , "alphabet" : "A"}, {"id" : "2" , "alphabet" : "B"}, {"id" : "3" , "alphabet" : "C"}, ]`

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```js
    var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    var array = arr.map((x) => ({ id:x }));
    console.log(array);


   var arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
    var array2 = arr2.map((x) => ({ alphabet:x }));
    console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
var arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']

var result = arr.map((v,i) => ({id:v, alphabet:arr2[i]}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What happen if arr  and arr2 have different length?

Comment: @NishantDixit - I am not sure whether this is even a test case with the OP. Let OP clarify on this and also share the desired result for it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass index as the second parameter in `map()` so that you can use that to take the number from the specific index. Try the following:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

var arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
var array2 = arr2.map((x,i) => ({id:arr[i], alphabet:x }));
console.log(array2);
```

**OR:** if the length of the arrays are not same:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

var arr2 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I']
var array2 = arr2.map(function(x,i){
  arr[i] = arr[i] || '';
  return {id:arr[i], alphabet:x}
});

console.log(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var arr2 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'];
var finalResult = arr.reduce((array, val, index) => {
    arr2[index] ? array.push({
        id: val,
        alphabet: arr2[index]
    }) : null;
    return array;
}, []);


console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

A much more easier way with different length of value arrays and with the potential to add some more arrays is to use an object with the keys as wanted key for the properties for the wanted new objects.

It works by using [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and later get the property name as key for the new object and the value as array for single values of the new object.

Inside of reduce, all values of the arrays are combined to a new object and assigned to the object at the same index. If that object does not exist, a new object is used.

```js
var id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I'],
    result = Object
        .entries({ id, alphabet })
        .reduce((r, [k, values]) => {
            values.forEach((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] = r[i] || {}, { [k]: v }));
            return r;
        }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```